# sails Sorry, this function doesn't know how to handle {...} callbacks

Tags: sails.js, sails-postgresql

Somehow, my sails.js 1.x  environment has gotten mangled to the point that I'm no longer able to do native queries to my PostgreSQL database.  I'm sure the issue is the version of some package or another, because I did some experimentation with NodeJS 9 over the weekend, but this code was working on Friday and I can't seen to find the issue.  Any suggestions?

```
sails> sails.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "user"').then(console.log);
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }

sails> UsageError: Sorry, this function doesn't know how to handle {...} callbacks.
If provided, the 2nd argument should be a function like `function(err,result){...}`
|  If you passed in {...} on purpose as a "switchback" (dictionary of callbacks),
|  please be aware that, as of machine v15, you can no longer pass in a switchback
|  as the 2nd argument.  And you can't pass a switchback in to .exec() anymore either.
|  Instead, you'll need to explicitly call .switch().
 [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for help.
    at /Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/lib/datastore-method-utils/private/do-with-connection.js:133:24
    at _makeCallToDuringFn (/Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/lib/datastore-method-utils/private/do-with-connection.js:101:28)
    at /Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/lib/datastore-method-utils/private/do-with-connection.js:103:7
    at /Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/lib/datastore-method-utils/private/do-with-connection.js:66:14
    at /Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/machinepack-postgresql/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:966:24
    at Function.handlerCbs.success (/Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/machinepack-postgresql/node_modules/machine/lib/private/help-build-machine.js:826:26)
    at cb (/Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/machinepack-postgresql/machines/get-connection.js:87:20)
    at BoundPool.<anonymous> (/Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:137:9)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at /Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:347:9
    at BoundPool.<anonymous> (/Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:103:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:158:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/patrick/src/healthcelerate/hc-registry/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:607:20)
sails>
```

Any tips or ideas would be much apprviated.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same error!

Comment: It turned out to be a bug in the version of sails I was running.  I upgraded sails to the latest (1.0.2 IIRC) and it resolved it.

Comment: I'm using `sails@1.0.2`. Could you please specify the `sails-postgresql` version

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a bug in the version of Sails we were running.  I upgraded sails to 1.0.2 and it resolved.

Comment: I deleted `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`. Did a `npm cache clean --force` and `npm install`. it worked "wierd"

Comment: For what it's worth, I've found many fewer problems with yarn vs. npm

Comment: Ok, will try that out. Thanks :)